# Are Haskell Pointers Pass by Value?

Tags: haskell, ffi

I have constructed a function of type `f :: Ptr Int -> IO (Int)`.

When I pass `f` some pointer `p`, and then try to `free p`, I get a core dump.

My conclusion is that Haskell passes pointers by reference and automatically deletes them after a value is returned from a function!

**Question:** When `f` is passed `p`, does it do so by value or by reference? Does Haskell delete `p` by the time the function returns?

Comment: Bit of example code please... it doesn't really make much sense to me what you're asking; a pointer is something quite different from the value it's pointing to.

Comment: Are you actually, y’know, allocating the pointer with `malloc`? The question of where you’re getting the pointer from is sort of important if you’re getting issues when you try to `free` it.

Comment: All haskell code (except for unboxed types) is pass by reference, if such a distinction is even meaningful in a non-strict language (because it implies an expression is always either a value or a reference). The docs say: "Free a block of memory that was allocated with malloc, mallocBytes, realloc, reallocBytes, new" - was your pointer created by one of these methods? If not, expect a core dump. (Your actual issue could be any number of things - you should post the actual code. This is just the most likely explanation in my experience).

Comment: @Alexis: See my comment sepp2k's answer. I was indeed trying to free non-malloced memory. Lesson learned!

Comment: By reference and by value are only two of the *many* types of arguments passing... sure they are the most common but remember that "¬ by reference ≠ by value" and "¬ by value ≠ by reference".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't free pointers, you free memory, specifically malloc (and co.)-allocated memory. If you free a pointer to something other than malloc-allocated memory, it fails. If you free a pointer to malloc-allocated memory that has already been freed, it also fails.

> When f is passed p, does it do so by value or by reference?

Usually values are in Haskell are boxed, unless you specifically use unboxed types. They're also usually lazy, so what you get is a box inside a thunk. I suppose that qualifies as passing by reference. That said, this isn't at all relevant to your problem. Pointers wouldn't behave any differently if you just passed their unboxed, strict, numeric values by value<sup>1</sup>.

> Does Haskell delete p by the time the function returns?

Absolutely not. Haskell does not automatically call `free` on any `Ptr`s. In the absence of garbage collection<sup>2</sup>, there's no way it could even know when it's safe to call `free` on a given pointer.

---

<sup>1</sup> With regards to your question that is.

<sup>2</sup> Now, of course, Haskell *is* garbage collected, but this doesn't apply to the values that you can have `Ptr`s to.

Comment: My pointer was created with the haskell function [with](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Utils.html#v:with), which takes care of the termination on its end. This explains why calling `free` caused a core dump. Lesson learned!